# Removing the contents of a Chan or MVar in a single discrete step

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a discrete simulation where request values from multiple threads accumulate in a centralized queue.  Every n milliseconds, a manager wakes up to process requests.  When the manager wakes up, it should retrieve *all* of the contents of the central queue in a single discrete step.  While processing these, any client threads attempting to submit to the queue should block.  When processing completes, the queue reopens and the manager goes back to sleep.

What's the best way to do this?  The retry behavior of STM isn't really what I want.  If I use a Chan or MVar, there's no way to prevent clients from enqueuing additional requests during processing.  One approach is to use an MVar as a mutex on a Chan holding the queue.  Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 5):

I'd have to benchmark under your expected contention levels to know exactly what the best solution is, but here's my guess.

Use an `MVar` containing `[Item]`, whatever your item type is.  Initialize the `MVar` with with `newMVar []`.  To add an element to the central list, use `modifyMVar_ (return . (item :))`, where `item` is what you are adding to the list.  Use `takeMVar` at the start of the processing pass, and `putMVar []` and the end of it.

First, note that this isn't a queue, internally.  If you want to handle things in the order they were added, `reverse` the list after extracting it.

Second, so long as these are the only operations you perform on the `MVar`, this is free of race conditions.  That's because the `MVar` is initialized full, and each operation is "take the contents of the `MVar`, put something else in."  Operations may block while waiting for the latter part of that, but this can't deadlock and there will be no lost updates.

Comment: Oh, you can avoid the `reverse` and keep things in order of insertion by using a slightly more complicated type inside the `MVar`.  I left that out because I don't think it's worth complicating my answer with.  But it is feasible, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there a problem with MVar [a] though?  When there are no items to be read we want readers to be blocked, but since the MVar actually contains [] this doesn't happen.

Comment: So in that case we will read out the empty list, decide there is no work to do and suspend (sleep) for another n milliseconds.  This reduces to no worse the polling for new work every n milliseconds.